# Android KITKAT VPNService Route Exclusion

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

It is know that IP exclusion is almost impossible using Android VPN Service API in NON ROOTED Device.

But I have rooted device . So I first connect VPN ( openvpn ). 
  After than from ADB ROOT SHELL - I run following command

**./route add -net <> netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.1**

For example if I run following command

./route add -net **141.101.120.15** netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.1

All traffic to   whatismyip [DOT] com  go directly ( Not passing  through VPN )
  Hence whatismyip.com reports my Local ISP IP in Its home page.

By these way I could exclude IPs from VPN path. This is working fine  in ICS and Jelly without any issue.

But this same procedure not working in KITKAT. I tested both in **4.4.2 and 4.4.4**

If I modify route, traffic still goes through VPN path. Whatismyip.com  displaying VPN Server IP in its home page.

My KITKAT routing table shows following same as ICS and jelly. Command is successfully executed in routing table..But just not working..

Can anybody please point out what changes I need to make for KITKAT.

```
**Fresh Routing Table**



ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  metric 324
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  scope link
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2  metric 324

192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  scope link


 **After VPN Connected**


ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  metric 324
172.22.1.4/30 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.22.1.6
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  scope link
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2  metric 324

192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  scope link



**After whatismyip.com [141.101.120.15]  exclusion**



ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  metric 324

**141.101.120.15 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0**

172.22.1.4/30 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.22.1.6
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  scope link
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2  metric 324
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  scope link
```

Thank you